# Somehow Microsoft is using protected method from SocketsHttpHandler but I can't

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create derived class from `HttpMessageHandler` exactly like it was done [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/35fe82c2e90fa345d0b6ad243c14da193fb123fd/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs#L14).
I stumbled right in the beginning, my code so far:

```
public class InternetClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        private readonly SocketsHttpHandler _socketsHttpHandler;

        public InternetClientHandler()
        {
            _socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _socketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken); //ERROR
        }
    }
```

This is an exact copy of Microsoft's implementation of `HttpClientHandler` but method `_socketsHttpHandler.SendAsync` doesn't compile because `SendAsync` of `SocketsHttpHandler` is protected. Why it works in MS's code but not in mine? Is it some sort of extension method? If so then why Intelli Sense doesn't provide help to insert the right using?

Comment: `SendAsync` is a `protected internal` method, meaning it can be called by both methods that override it, and methods internal to the assembly. The latter is what makes the code work for MS but not for you. All you have available is a call to `base.SendAsync`; wrapping instances of different types and calling `SendAsync` directly is not possible.

Comment: You are looking at library source code (namespace System.Net.Http).  So inside the library you can execute private objects while you can't from outside the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access `SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync` because it is marked as [`protected internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal). This means you either need to be in the same assembly (ie Microsoft's code), or you need to inherit from it. And you can't inherit because it's marked as `sealed`.

Instead, you should inherit from [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=net-7.0), which *is* part of the same assembly and therefore able to call it. This was designed for exactly this scenario.

```cs
public class InternetClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public InternetClientHandler() : base(new SocketsHttpHandler())
    {
        // change InnerHandler properties here
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do stuff
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken); // will call InnerHandler.SendAsync
    }
}
```